# How to performs multiple query on the database Oracle using PHP Language

Tags: php, oracle

In order to run a query for database MySQL, we are using mysqli_query. Then, for running a query for database Oracle, we are using oci_execute.

When we wish to running multiple query for database MySQL, we are using mysqli_multi_query. Example as below:-

```
$mysqliconn = mysqliconn();         //mysqli connection
$sql = '
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES();
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES();
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES();
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES();
';
if(mysqli_multi_query($mysqliconn, $sql)) {
    echo 'Success';
}
```

My Question is if there anyone of you whom can come out with the most simplest solution to run multiple inserting values into the database table using one command execution.

Comment: There's a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449132/run-mysql-insert-query-multiple-times-insert-values-into-multiple-tables Would that help?

Comment: @Hugo nope, the question is for Oracle.

Comment: Mimi in MySQL the way you've shown us isn't the best way to insert multiple entries. You should rather use `INSERT INTO table VALUES (), (), ();`

Comment: By the way, if your question is about Oracle, don't tag other RDBMS

Comment: @Hugo, my question is for Oracle. I just give an example in MySQL. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has an [`INSERT ALL`](https://www.javatpoint.com/oracle-insert-all) statement for that.
Otherwise you could just loop in your code and execute it n times.

Comment: [`INSERT ALL`](https://www.javatpoint.com/oracle-insert-all) statement is really works. Thank you for giving me a new knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = '
INSERT INTO TABLE abc VALUES(123,'xyz'),(456,'def'),(789,'qwe');
';
```

I suggest that using support library ^^

Comment: this doesn't work in Oracle